# how can I send the image using bluetooth in discoverable device name with image using CoreBluetooth in swift 5

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, swift5

using central and peripheral in two iOS devices

one is sender another one is receiver ,searching the near by device show the name with image ,how can I share it please give me solution .

currently I have use this method:

```
let advertisementData = String(format: "%@", a)
peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:[Constants.SERVICE_UUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: advertisementData])


func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {

    for request in requests {
        if let value = request.value {

            let messageText = String(data: value, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?
            print(messageText as Any)
            if messageText == "Received:Success"
            {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "csvc", sender: self)
            }
           // appendMessageToChat(message: Message(text: messageText!, isSent: false))
        }
        self.peripheralManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
    }
}
```

Comment: "the name with image " What image? What's your question exactly?

Comment: png image with discovering.

Comment: I need to create an app like share it ,sender and receiver ,sender find the device ,receiver wait ,sender select to connect the device how?
please give a sample code.

Comment: first of all sender scanning the device the receiver device show with name and image ,which code can I use to connect ,then sharing both device after connected.